# In Intellij Idea, how to keep showing context information?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know for sure that by clicking hot key *alt + q*, the context of current method or class could show up just like:
[image]

But is there any way to make the IDE keep showing the context information at the top of the edit area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep the method definition for the 'currently active' method pinned to the top of the editor but if your goal is to display the method definition for the 'currently active' method while you are editing that method then you could use the `Structure` tool window and select `Autoscroll from source`. This will show you the definition of the method you are currently editing / your cursor is currently sitting in.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

`Autoscroll from source` is the last icon on the right at the top of the `Structure` tool window.

You can activate the `Structure` tool window via keystokes (e.g. `ALT 7`), to identify the correct keystroke just have a look at the keystroke associated with the menu item: `View > Tool Windows > Structure`.

More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structure-tool-window-file-structure-popup.html)

Comment: I just remember when I was working for my last company, the context of the currently active method was pinned to top of the edit panel. However, it never happen again in any of the Intellij Idea I used after I left the company. Now I am wondering it might relate to the version of Intellij Idea. And one more  thing, my last company has a limited internet access, so Intellij Idea is not able to update itself constantly without a network proxy.

Comment: I also have the same experience. I think it was in Android Studio that is strongly based on IntelliJ..